# how to send an id from the view to a component in angular 5?

Tags: mysql, angular5

This is my view

```
`<div *ngFor="let post of losPosts; ">
     <h2>Fecha: {{post.fecha}}</h2>
     <p>{{post.contenido}}</p>
     <div *ngFor="let com of losComentarios(id_post)">
      <h2>Fecha: {{com.fecha}}</h2>
      <p>{{com.comentario}}</p> 
     </div>
   </div>`
```

This is my component function

```
` obtenerComentarios(id){
    this.datos.getComentarios(id)
        .then(
            data => {
            console.log(data[0]);
            //this.losDatos = data[0].nombres;
            this.losComentarios = data;
        }) ;
  }`

This is a "obtenerposts()" 


`obtenerPosts(){
    this.datos.getPosts()
        .then(
          data => {
            console.log(data[0]);
            //this.losDatos = data[0].nombres;
            this.losPosts = data;
       }) ;
    }`
```

My question is: how to send an id from the view using a function "obtenerComentarios(id)" towards a component in angular 5?

Comment: If you want `id` from `x` component to `y` component, you can use observables, subject

Comment: Interesting I´m going try it.